What is this game type called?
In recent ads a clickbait game called Hero Wars have been faking being a game that scrolls forward, while picking up powerups and shooting enemies. I've been trying to find other games like this (because Hero Wars is a fake game that doesn't do this), but I can't figure out what this game type is called. I would guess a form of scroller, but that doesn't seem to exist.
Basically the game is your character is at the bottom, enemies spawn at the top, and they move downward towards you, and you shoot them. You pick up powerups and other things to make yourself more powerful. At the end, there might be a boss.
This is nostalgia from my childhood, when there were arcade games like this, then you would often control an airplane. I'm trying to find a game like this.
What are these games called?

The arcade games you reference sound very much like your standard vertical SHMUP -- or "Shoot'em Up".
The arcade console I remember most from my own childhood was 1942, which had you flying a fighterplane against massive enemy forces (and the occasional giant mecha).

It looks like a version is on the Google play store if you'd like to verify it for yourself.

That definitely looks like the game. I googled a bit and found "vertically scrolling shoot em up", which sounds a bit more specific. 1941 rings a lot of bells, that might be it exactly. Thanks for this!

You might be interested to know that the vertical shmup genre evolved in interesting ways since the arcade games of the 80s and 90s. The bullet hell/bullet curtain/danmaku subgenre has grown pretty popular; these games see you dodging waves of hundreds of bullets that fill the whole screen, sometimes with extra bonuses granted for bullets that graze the edge of your hit box without actually hitting you. On lower difficulties these are reminiscent of old arcade shmups and would probably scratch that nostalgia itch.

A few things to remember before I answer your question: Hero Wars ads are nearly the only game that actually have this game type, other than some other rip-offs.
This type of game is called "Tower Wars", "Tower Puzzles", or sometimes "Battle Puzzles". This is under the category, generally, of Puzzles.
